# Design pattern to use when multiple calls to the webservices are done

Tags: java, rest, web-services, design-patterns, microservices

I am developing a microservice which calls 4 different soap webservices one after the other and response of each soap service is fed as the input request to the subsequent soap webservice. The scenario is explained as below:

```
micrservice
|------------------> soap service 1
       if(soap_Service1_Response.indicator is 1)
        {
                 call soap webservice 2(responseOfsoapService1)
         }
        else if(soap_Service1_Response.indicator is 2)
        {
                call soap webservice 3(responseOfsoapService2)
        }
         ........and so on.
```

Which design pattern to use in this scenario so that multiple if and else need not to be written?
    Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be the [Chain of Responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility)

You have a *processor* object which has a reference to *next* processor. The first processor runs the request and passes the result to the next processor which runs next request and passes its result to next processor and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The **State Pattern** would simplify/ modularize your code. See [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/java/1)

Comment: Links get broken in time. As it is this answer should have been a comment. To provide an answer based on the link, the relevant part of it should be included in the body of the answer.